# systemd: stop boot process on failure (actually make a shutdown)

Tags: systemd, startup, shutdown

How is possible to immediately stop the bootup process, show some message (quit splash screen) and shutdown machine if a oneshot service fails?

My service starts just one script. If something went wrong, or better said, if a special condition occurs, I'd like to shutdown the machine. So far, I tried to put inside the script a `systemctl poweroff`. But unfortunately, this call immediately returns and the bootup process is continued normally doing the shutdown more or less parallel. In my case, the login-screen appears for a few seconds until the poweroff is finally done.

Here is my unit-file:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Fancy Script
Before=NetworkManager.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/path/to/script
StandardOutput=journal+console

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

I even tried to use `FailureAction=` but that doesn't work either.

Any ideas how to do this? There must be a "typical" way. For example, if a mountpoint could not be loaded, the system is put into maintenance mode (this ctrl-D thing ;) ) and the bootup is interrupted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There must be a "typical" way. For example, if a mountpoint could not be loaded, the system is put into maintenance mode and the bootup is interrupted.

Yes, there is.  And if you look at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target` you will find that it is

```
OnFailure=emergency.target
OnFailureJobMode=replace-irreversibly
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple options. One is the brutal option, which may be appropriate for a
stateless system that can't be corrupted. That is to add the `--force` option to `poweroff`

```
poweroff --force
```

The docs for it say: "Force immediate halt, power-off, reboot. Do not contact the init system.".

Other services will continue to start in parallel, but the power down should happen faster.

---

The behavior you are seeing is because systemd is trying to boot your system as
fast possible by doing as much as possible as in parallel. This means it moves
on to a next task as soon a dependency is fulfilled, not necessarily when a
service finishes running.

Since the login screen and other services don't depend on your service running,
they are being started in parallel, even as the shutdown sequence has started
to run.

You could solve your issue by forcing the boot process to pause and wait for
your task to finish before proceeding. First, decide what services should start
until your custom service finishes, then add those services or targets to your file
with new [Before=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Before=) entries.